# на кнопке событие онклик нажав на которую нужно получить сумму цифр многозначного числа

Tags: javascript

```js
function num3() {
    let x = +numbers.value
    //тут застрял
    result.innerHTML = 'result is = '+ 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div style="margin: auto">
   <input id="numbers">
   <br>
   <br>
  
   <button onclick="num3()">сумма цифр многозначного числа</button>
   <br>
   <h1 id="result"></h1>
   </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function num3() {
  let x = numbers.value
  result.innerHTML = 'result is = ' + x.split("").reduce((r, a) => +a + r, 0);
}
```

```html
<div style="margin: auto">
  <input id="numbers" value="12345">
  <br>
  <br>

  <button onclick="num3()">сумма цифр многозначного числа</button>
  <br>
  <h1 id="result"></h1>
</div>
```

```js
function num3() {
  let x = numbers.value;
  let digits = x.split(""); // array of characters
  let res = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
    res += parseInt(digits[i]);
  }
  result.innerHTML = 'result is = ' + res;
}
```

```html
<div style="margin: auto">
  <input id="numbers" value="12345">
  <br>
  <br>

  <button onclick="num3()">сумма цифр многозначного числа</button>
  <br>
  <h1 id="result"></h1>
</div>
```

Comment: объясните пожалуйста этот код, что есть что? .split("").reduce((r, a) => +a + r, 0)

Comment: @Vahan Добавил второй вариант - подробный.

Answer (score 1):

Ещё вариант

```js
    function num3() {
        let x = numbers.value;
        var result1 = eval(x.toString().split('').join('+'));
        result.innerHTML = 'result is = ' + result1;
        }
```

```html
<body>
   <div style="margin: auto">
   <input id="numbers">
   <br>
   <br>

   <button onclick="num3()">сумма цифр многозначного числа</button>
   <br>
   <h1 id="result"></h1>
   </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```