# для чего нужна функция reduce в js объясните пожалуйста этот код, не понимаю

Tags: javascript

```js
 let x = numbers.value;
        result.innerHTML = 'result is = ' + x.split("").reduce((r, a) => +a + r, 0);
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: Ъто сумма цифр введённого в инпут числа.

Comment: Причём из соседнего вопроса: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1071254/178988.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Reduce` - это способ перебора массива похожий на `foreach` и `for`, но отличается одной особенностью. 
А именно - он проходит по массиву, и сохраняет полученный результат, как значение своей переменной.

Если простыми словами, на Вашем примере - то `x.split("")` разбивает число на цифры, занося их в массив, дальше `reduce((r, a) => +a + r, 0)` перебирает каждое число массива и выполняет действие, а именно `+a + r`, где `+a` это приведение значения в числовой формат, а `+ r` функция сложения.
Проходя по каждому элементу массива (цифре из числа, так как его разбили с помощью `split`), и к текущему значению прибавляет новый найденный элемент, после чего результат он сохраняет в своём первом параметре `r` и снова проходит по массиву, выполняя действия.

В итоге в Вашей функции мы получаем:

```
 let x = numbers.value; // Получаем значение поля с `id` `numbers`
        result.innerHTML = 'result is = ' + x.split("").reduce((r, a) => +a + r, 0); // Разбиваем полученное число на цифры, и складываем их по очереди.
```

По факту Ваше выражение складывает все цифры в числе.

Пример:

```js
    function bzz(){
        let x = numbers.value;
        result.innerHTML = 'result is = ' + x.split("").reduce((r, a) => +a + r, 0);
    }
```

```html
<body>
    <input id="numbers">
    <div id="result"></div>
    <button onclick="bzz();">Тык</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

На примере простой задачи: Посчитать сумму всех элементов массива.

Для этого обычно создают переменную со значением `0`, запускают цикл по массиву и на каждом круге добавляют очередное число из массива в общую сумму:

```js
let arr = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1];

console.log( "sum (for) → ", demo_for(arr) );

function demo_for(arr){
  let sum = 0;
  for( let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ){
    let elem = arr[i];
    sum = sum + elem;
    
    console.log(
      "for: Значение sum → " + sum,
      " /// array elem → " + elem,
      " /// iteration → " + i
    );
  }
  
  return sum;
}
```

А reduce позволяет пропустить строчку с созданием переменной и указать её начальное значение сразу в качестве второго аргумента `reduce(функция, начальное_значение)` — причем, **первый** параметр переданной функции на первой итерации получит это начальное значение, а дальше в первом параметре будет храниться то, что на каждой итерации начнет возвращать функция. Так:

```js
let arr = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1];

console.log("sum (reduce) → ", demo_reduce(arr));
console.log("sum (forEach) → ", demo_forEach(arr));

function demo_reduce(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function(sum, elem, i, arr) {
    sum = sum + elem;

    console.log(
      "reduce: Значение sum → " + sum,
      " /// array elem → " + elem,
      " /// iteration → " + i
    );

    return sum;
    // Значение, которое возвращает функция - записывается в переменную sum
    // которое будет доступно на следующей итерации.
  }, 0);
}

/* То же самое */

function demo_forEach(arr) {
  let sum = 0;
  arr.forEach(function(elem, i, arr) {
    sum = sum + elem;
  });
  
  return sum
}
```

Т.е. reduce может пригодится везде, где есть какая-то начальная переменная и цикл, делающий что-то с этой переменной. Полезно понимать, что любой reduce можно переписать в обычный цикл. Пример:

```js
let main = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

// reduce

let bubu = main.reduce(function(arr, elem, i) {
  arr.push( elem * elem ) // на каждой итерации добавляем туда квадрат числа
  return arr; // и передаем получившийся массив в руки следующей итерации
}, []) // ← начиная с пустого массива...

console.log( JSON.stringify( bubu ) );

// ровно то же самое на for

let arr = [];
for( i = 0; i < main.length; i++ ){
  let elem = main[i];
  arr.push( elem * elem );
}

console.log( JSON.stringify( arr ) );
```

Ну а у вас стрелочная функция:

```
(r, a) => +a + r
```

↑↓

```
function(r, a) {
  return +a + r;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reduce.asp

Функция `reduce` используется, чтобы превратить много вещей (элементы массива) вo что-то одно.